Hosting ASP.NET Core self-contain web application on Raspberry Pi issue
I have an issue with hosting a self-contained ASP.NET Core web application on Raspberry Pi. When I try to run the application I get this error:
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ConsolidatedAssemblyApplicationPartFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetTypeCore(String, ReadOnlySpan`1, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.TypeNameParser.GetType(String, ReadOnlySpan`1, String)
   at System.Reflection.TypeNameParser.NamespaceTypeName.ResolveType(TypeNameParser&, String)
   at System.Reflection.TypeNameParser.Parse()
   at System.Reflection.TypeNameParser.GetType(String, Func`2, Func`4, Assembly, Boolean , Boolean , Boolean )
   at System.Reflection.TypeNameParser.GetType(String, Assembly, Boolean , Boolean )
   at System.Type.GetType(String, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ProvideApplicationPartFactoryAttribute.GetFactoryType()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(Assembly)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection, IWebHostEnvironment)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddRazorPagesCore(IServiceCollection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddRazorPages(IServiceCollection)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[]) in C:\Users\mihas\source\repos\HelloWorld\Program.cs:line 4
Aborted

In my application on line 4 there is a code:
// Add services to the container. 
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
I don't understand. If the application is self-contained it should work regardless of the runtime being installed or not on the device which is going to run the application. Does someone know what I'm missing?
I also tried a Framework-dependent solution and installed the latest Framework on my RPI, but I got a similar error.

Is this self-contained projects work well during local test? I mean directly running this self-contained application inside the development computer.

Yes, the project runs just fine on the development computer.

Looks like this issue is still related with the runtime, could you please run the published self-contained application to the other server which doesn't install the .net core runtime?

It looks like the issue was in Visual Studio. Despite that, I selected a self-contained application it was built as framework-dependent.
After rebooting the Visual Studio and publishing as framework-dependent and then changing back to self-contained it worked.
